# What happens when you use your Google Account for Trello?

Tags: gmail, google, google-calendar, trello, synchronization

I can't seem to find an explanation or detail on what happens, what is synchronized, if, when you use Trello with a Gmail or Google account? Can you synch the Task list? Calendars? Emails? Where does it live? What does it look like?

Comment: It would be amazing to syncronize with Google Calendar :)

Answer (score 6):

Google is just the OpenID provider. Jeff Atwood explains OpenID rather well in this blog post:

[OpenID: Does The World Really Need Yet Another Username and Password?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/openid-does-the-world-really-need-yet-another-username-and-password.html)

Answer (score 4):

There is no synchronization. You use your Gmail/Google-account to login on Trello. So instead of using/creating a new login on yet-another-webservice you re-use your previous account.

Answer (score 0):

We're trying to get your profile picture from Google, at some point in the future, too. Right now, people have to create an account at gravatar.org to get one.